# namenode is not formatted in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, installation

In normal account.

I created some directories.

```
/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namenode
/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namesecondary
/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/datanode
/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/yarn/nm-local-dir
/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/yarn/system/rmstore
```

And typed some commands

```
bin/hdfs namenode –format
sudo sbin/start-all.sh
jps
```

Then

In the normal account, I could see only jps.

In the root account, I could see Jps, DataNode, SecondaryNameNode, NodeManager and ResourceManager.

I have 2 questions.

1. Why can I see only jps in normal account?
2. Why is namenode not started?

Thanks for reading.
And if you help me, I will appreciate you.

namenode log file

```html
2017-04-06 01:16:15,217 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-04-06 01:16:15,220 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: createNameNode []
2017-04-06 01:16:15,680 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-04-06 01:16:15,843 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2017-04-06 01:16:15,843 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2017-04-06 01:16:15,845 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: fs.defaultFS is hdfs://localhost:9010
2017-04-06 01:16:15,846 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Clients are to use localhost:9010 to access this namenode/service.
2017-04-06 01:16:16,070 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil: Starting Web-server for hdfs at: http://localhost:50070
2017-04-06 01:16:16,152 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2017-04-06 01:16:16,158 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2017-04-06 01:16:16,165 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.namenode is not defined
2017-04-06 01:16:16,169 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2017-04-06 01:16:16,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context hdfs
2017-04-06 01:16:16,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2017-04-06 01:16:16,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2017-04-06 01:16:16,300 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter 'org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter' (class=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter)
2017-04-06 01:16:16,303 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: addJerseyResourcePackage: packageName=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.web.resources;org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources, pathSpec=/webhdfs/v1/*
2017-04-06 01:16:16,330 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 50070
2017-04-06 01:16:16,330 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2017-04-06 01:16:16,581 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@localhost:50070
2017-04-06 01:16:16,612 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-04-06 01:16:16,612 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-04-06 01:16:16,613 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one image storage directory (dfs.namenode.name.dir) configured. Beware of data loss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2017-04-06 01:16:16,613 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one namespace edits storage directory (dfs.namenode.edits.dir) configured. Beware of data loss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2017-04-06 01:16:16,617 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-04-06 01:16:16,617 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-04-06 01:16:16,639 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
2017-04-06 01:16:16,639 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
2017-04-06 01:16:16,668 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
2017-04-06 01:16:16,668 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
2017-04-06 01:16:16,669 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
2017-04-06 01:16:16,669 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2017 Apr 06 01:16:16
2017-04-06 01:16:16,670 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2017-04-06 01:16:16,670 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2017-04-06 01:16:16,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 19.3 MB
2017-04-06 01:16:16,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2017-04-06 01:16:16,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
2017-04-06 01:16:16,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
2017-04-06 01:16:16,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
2017-04-06 01:16:16,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
2017-04-06 01:16:16,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
2017-04-06 01:16:16,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
2017-04-06 01:16:16,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
2017-04-06 01:16:16,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
2017-04-06 01:16:16,706 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = root (auth:SIMPLE)
2017-04-06 01:16:16,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
2017-04-06 01:16:16,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
2017-04-06 01:16:16,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
2017-04-06 01:16:16,708 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
2017-04-06 01:16:16,963 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
2017-04-06 01:16:16,963 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2017-04-06 01:16:16,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 9.7 MB
2017-04-06 01:16:16,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
2017-04-06 01:16:16,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
2017-04-06 01:16:16,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
2017-04-06 01:16:16,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
2017-04-06 01:16:16,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2017-04-06 01:16:16,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
2017-04-06 01:16:16,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2017-04-06 01:16:16,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 966.7 MB = 2.4 MB
2017-04-06 01:16:16,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
2017-04-06 01:16:16,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
2017-04-06 01:16:16,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2017-04-06 01:16:16,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
2017-04-06 01:16:16,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.top.metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
2017-04-06 01:16:16,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.top.metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
2017-04-06 01:16:16,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.top.metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
2017-04-06 01:16:16,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
2017-04-06 01:16:16,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
2017-04-06 01:16:16,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
2017-04-06 01:16:16,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2017-04-06 01:16:16,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 966.7 MB = 297.0 KB
2017-04-06 01:16:16,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
2017-04-06 01:16:17,005 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namenode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 5360@localhost
2017-04-06 01:16:17,007 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:225)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:975)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:812)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:796)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1493)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
2017-04-06 01:16:17,032 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@localhost:50070
2017-04-06 01:16:17,035 WARN org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer Acceptor: isRunning is false. Rechecking.
2017-04-06 01:16:17,035 WARN org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer Acceptor: isRunning is false
2017-04-06 01:16:17,035 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2017-04-06 01:16:17,035 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2017-04-06 01:16:17,035 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2017-04-06 01:16:17,035 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:225)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:975)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:812)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:796)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1493)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
2017-04-06 01:16:17,036 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2017-04-06 01:16:17,040 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can I see only jps in normal account?

As you have started the daemons with `sudo`, `root` user owns the processes. The command `jps` reports only the JVMs for which it has the access permissions. The normal account has no access for the processes owned by `root`.

> Why is namenode not started?

```
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
```

Namenode is not yet formatted. It is possible that you have missed to provide `Y` when the format command prompted for `(Y/N)`.

Comment: Are there problems? when I use hadoop in normal account . hadoop was started with sudo

Comment: Start it without using `sudo`. Then it will be listed  under `jps`. Before starting make sure the namenode is successfully formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether properties are properly set are not in core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Then run the following command

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but check the ownership of the namenode folder.

It should be hadoop  user or associate user which has authority to access this folder.

I have the same issue and solved by chnaging the ownership of the folder. Also assign full permission to the folder.

Hope this  helps.